# Robot class do not work in IE for the file upload scenario

Tags: file-upload, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11

I came across this situation in a file upload scenario ..This works very well in chrome and in firefox...but not in Internet Explorer 11. In IE the model dialogue doesnt open and it's not pasting the path of the file which is suppose to be uploaded Is any one facing this issue in IE Do we have to do anything extra to do this in IE Please let me know.

Comment: Can you add more details to your question like language, your code...?

Comment: i tried to automate using Java code..please see my code below.

Comment: you should add the relevant code to your question by editing it; pl don't post it as an answer (to your own question)..

Comment: Mukesh -- I tried to post this code for my question but got many errors and at last i pasted this in the answer section. Apologize for the inconvenience.

Answer (score -1):

System.out.println("Upload the document in the form");

driver1.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.doc-upload")).sendKeys("C:\Users\wb470668\Desktop\PPF Documents\Test Document\Test Doc1 (2).docx");

System.out.println("Button is clicked");
        Thread.sleep(5000);

```
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.delay(1500);
    //robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    //robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        // Release
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    // Press Enter
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    Thread.sleep(6000);
```